# Database import from MDB to SQL datatype problem

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import

I'm having some problems when importing an MDB database, specifically on a column that contains a date but is declared as NVARCHAR(12), I import the MDB database every day so I cannot change the data type in my SQL database because the next day gives me errors while importing the new data.
Is it possible to request a data type change when importing the new data?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of important details. Try editing like this: I have data in A that looks like this: [table]. I import it into B by doing C, getting error D.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import, but *link* the table.

Then run an *append query* having the linked table as source, and where you convert the textdate field to a true date field using `DateValue` or `CDate` to convert.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I need import because the MDB database is locally in a production machine that clears every day the data.

Comment: Eh? That makes no difference. The link is only used during the import done by the append query. When done, the linked file can be replaced at any time or even removed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a staging table with the same datatypes as in your source.  First you import into this table.  Next you cleanse the staging table.  And finally insert the result in your final table.